# How to tell whether a process is network I/O intensive or not in user mode in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, process, monitoring, io

I am currently writing a program in Linux which needs to tell whether a specific process is network I/O intensive  or not at runtime. I have tried some tools such as `iotop` and `iftop`, but none of them can monitor a specific process. So, are there any ways to tell whether a process is network I/O intensive or not in user level? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please add to the unix/Linux version and distribution

Answer (score 0):

You could check what its waiting channel is with some frequency.
The average waiting channel you encounter should be indicative of where the time is spent in the process.

E.g.: Take downloading a Ubuntu image as a typical net-io-bound process:

```
$ url='http://mirror.dkm.cz/ubuntu-releases/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
$ wget "$url" & pid=$!
```

When you do:

```
$ ps h -p $pid  -o wchan
```

You should get **poll_schedule_timeout** pretty much all the time, ergo it's a net-io-bound process that probably uses **epoll** for net io.

In contrast for a typically CPU-bound process such as:

```
$ ( while :; do :; done )& pid=$!
```

you should get a waiting channel of **-** ( = none = it's on a CPU core) pretty much all the time.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!  I tried with netperf (netserver) , but I always got a waiting channel of '-'. It it because the netserver is just a  I/O intensive process but not a I/O bound process?